# Threshold several variables into a binary categorical code in python

Tags: python, numpy, binary, categorical-data

I have 3 variables in python (age, gender, race) and I want to create a unique categorical binary code out of them. Firstly, the age is an integer and I want to threshold it for each decade 10-20, 20-30, 30-40 etc., gender 2 values and the race contains 4 values. How can I return a complete categorical code out of the three initial variables?

Comment: I find your question interesting but did not understand anything. I tried googling "categorical binary code" but found nothing.

Comment: Not sure if it is accurate term. I want a binary code for my variables. I know in python there is this method that you can input integer and output a binary code am not sure how can I do so for the three variables combined.

Comment: Do you expect the binary code to be a list, a string, a byte or something else? For example:
code = [0,1,1,0], "0110" or b'0110'

Comment: I want my output to be a numpy array.

Comment: Before trying a response, Are your inputs integers for three features? 
Age: 0-10, gender:0-1, race:0-3?

Comment: They are strings but of course can be converted easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method returning a 7 bit code with first 4 bits for age bracket, next 2 for race, and 1 for gender.

4 bits for age imposes the constraint that there can be a total of 16 age brackets only, which is reasonable as it covers the age range 0-159.

The 4 bit age code is simply the 4 bit representation of the integer `age//10`, which effectively discretizes the age value into ranges: 0-9, 10-19, ..., 150-159

The codes for race and gender are simply hard coded using the `race_dict` and `gender_dict`

```
def get_code(age, race, gender): #returns fixed size 7 bit code
    race_dict = {'African':'00','Hispanic':'01','European':'10','Cantonese':'11'} 
    gender_dict = {'Male':'0','Female':'1'}

    age_code = '{0:b}'.format(age//10).zfill(4)
    race_code = race_dict[race]
    gender_code = gender_dict[gender]

    return  age_code + race_code + gender_code
```

> Input: age:25, race: 'Hispanic', gender: 'Female'
>
> 7-bit code: 0010011

If you would like this code to be an integer value between 0-127 for numerical purposes, you can use `int(code_str, 2)` to achieve that.

**EDIT:**

to get a numpy array from code string, use `np_code_arr = np.fromstring(' '.join(list(code_str)), dtype = int, sep = ' ')`

Comment: Can I map the return code to numpy array [0,0,1,0,0,1,1]?

Comment: @JoseRamon the most straightforward way seems to be to iterate through the string and populate a numpy array character by character

Comment: Do you have an example for that? Maybe another post.

Comment: @JoseRamon Nevermind, `np_code_arr = np.fromstring(' '.join(list(code_str)), dtype = int, sep = ' ') ` seems to do the trick in a single line
`

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `n+1+4` dimensional vector encoding. Given binary code you require, this would be one way of doing it.

You first `n` entries would encode decade. `1` if it belongs to that decade, `0` else. Next `(n+1)th` entry could be `1` if male and `0` if female. Similarly for race, `1` if it belongs to that category, `0` else.

Let's say you have up to decades up 100. For 98 year old, male, white, you could do something like `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0]` assuming you start from `10` year to `100`.

```
import numpy as np

def encodeAge(i, n):
    ageCode=np.zeros(n)
    ageCode[i]=1
    return ageCode

n=10 # number of decades
dict_race={'w':[1,0,0,0],'b':[0,1,0,0],'a':[0,0,1,0],'l':[0,0,0,1]} # white, black, asian, latino
dict_age={i:encodeAge(i, n) for i in range(n)}
dict_gender={'m':[1],'f':[0]}

def encodeAll(age, gender, race):
    # encode age
    code=[]
    code=np.concatenate([code, dict_age[age//10]])
    # encode gender
    code=np.concatenate([code, dict_gender[gender]])
    # encode race
    code=np.concatenate([code, dict_race[race]])
    return code
```

e.g. `encodeAll(12,'m','w')` would return `array([0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.])`

This is slightly longer encoding than other encodings suggested.

Answer (score 1):

My answer here:

Being age **a**, gender **g** and race **r**,

```
code = np.array([int(i) for i in "{0:04b}{1:01b}{2:02b}".format(a//10,g,r)])
```

for age=58, gender=1 and race=3, output will be:

```
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```